# Is there a way to get the response after saving data in Firestore?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using python to add data in firestore and I would want to get a response from firestore so that I can know if the data was successfully added or not. Is there a way to do this using Python? Newbie here.

I've already searched from other resources but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Firestore documentation in the code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/firestore/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.py#L205), the `DocumentReference.set()` method returns a:

> `google.cloud.firestore_v1.types.WriteResult`: The write result corresponding to the committed document. A write result contains an `update_time` field.

I can't find any Python examples, but it should work similarly to the Node.js version here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.2.x/WriteResult